# Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response when response size exceeds 1021 characters

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am developing a Google Action with Dialogflow fulfillment and have a strange error.
At some point the answer is not correctly parsed into an AppResponse although it is correctly formed.

The only different seems to be the size. I measured the size and found out that when the JSON response from by backend exceeds 1021 characters (one character more in the text is enough), it gives me this error:

***Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response***

It is reproducable to only add one additional character in the response text and it let's the response fail.

I cannot find any size limitation regarding the JSON response. All limitations in the response text & card are sufficient for my example.

```
{
"payload": {
    "google": {
        "expectUserResponse": true,
        "richResponse": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "simpleResponse": {
                        "textToSpeech": "328 characters here"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "basicCard": {
                        "title": "39 characters",
                        "subtitle": "16 characters",
                        "formattedText": "82 characters here"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "suggestions": [
                {
                    "title": "13 characters"
                },
                {
                    "title": "14 characters"
                },
                {
                    "title": "6 characters"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
"outputContexts": [
    {
        "name": "default",
        "lifespanCount": 99,
        "parameters": {
            "data": "54 characters"
        }
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually related to the NodeJS Express server compression, combined with the AWS API Gateway.
After a certain treshold, the Express server activates the GZIP content-encoding, that the AWS API Gateway does not understand. Disabling the compression solved the issue.